# Attention mechanism in LSTM model to predict next action

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, attention

I have a dataset. Each data point of this set contains a variable length of sequences with 7 letters. For example, Data point 1 has a sequence (A, A, B, E, B, C, D, E, D.....). I used LSTM to predict the next letter from this dataset. I know that adding **Attention mechanism** can improve the prediction accuracy. I searched for the background of how actually attention mechanism works. I came across various models which work well on the encoder-decoder problem. I am wondering in my case (i.e., predicting the next action/word) how **Attention mechanism** can improve the accuracy. If anyone can give some intuition or reference, it will be a great benefit for me.

Comment: if you've read up on attention mechanisms then what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Actually, I didn't get good intuition how it works. Particularly, how it can improve the prediction accuracy. So I am looking for some mathematical reference or explanation

Comment: When I learned the attention mechanism I read this paper: [Effective Approaches to Attention-based Neural Machine Translation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/emnlp15_attn.pdf). I think you can utilize the global attention mechnism in your case.

Comment: What is the task? Classification generating one single letter or generating a sequence which is a follow-up of a sequence you already have?